# 11g Oracle aggregate SQL query

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, aggregate-functions

Can you please help me in getting a query for this scenario. In below case it should return me single row of A=13 because 13,14 in column A has most occurrences and value of B (30) is greater for 13. We are interested in maximum occurrences of A and in case of tie B should be considered as tie breaker.

```
A   B
13  30
13  12
14  10
14  25
15  5
```

In below case where there are single occurrence of A (all tied) it should return 14 having maximum value of 40 for B.

```
A   B
13  30
14  40
15  5
```

Use case - we get calls from corporate customers. We are interested in knowing during what hours of day when most calls come and in case of tie - which of the busiest hours has longest call.

Further question

There is further questions on this. I want to use either of two solutions - '11g or lower' from @GurV or 'dense_rank' from @mathguy  in bigger query below how can I do it.

```
    SELECT dv.id , u.email , dv.email_subject AS headline , dv.start_date , dv.closing_date, b.name AS business_name, ls.call_cost, dv.currency,
    SUM(lsc.duration) AS duration,  COUNT(lsc.id) AS call_count, ROUND(AVG(lsc.duration), 2) AS avg_duration 
    -- max(extract(HOUR from started )) keep (dense_rank last order by count(duration), max(duration)) as most_popular_hour
    FROM deal_voucher dv
        JOIN lead_source ls ON dv.id = ls.deal_id
        JOIN lead_source_call lsc ON ls.PHONE_SID = lsc.phone_number_id
        JOIN business b ON dv.business_id = b.id
        JOIN users u ON b.id = u.business_id
        AND TRUNC(dv.closing_date) = to_date('13-01-2017', 'dd-mm-yyyy')
        AND lsc.status = 'completed' and lsc.duration >= 30
    GROUP BY dv.id , u.email , dv.email_subject , dv.start_date , dv.closing_date, b.name, ls.call_cost, dv.currency
--, extract(HOUR from started )
```

Comment: if 14, then total will be 35 and not 40! do you mean to group these by A column and sum B values?

Comment: @Smart that's not expected output, that's second case of input

Comment: @smart thanks. It has nothing to do with sum of B. B is call duration in minutes.

Comment: What do you need to return if there are ties by both criteria? As in the second example, there are no duplicates in A, but all values in B are the same (let's say 30)? Also - what version of Oracle do you have, since different tools are available in different versions? Actually never mind the last question, I see 11g in the title, it should also be in the tags. I'll edit the tags for you in a second.

Comment: @mathguy Thanks. I think it wouldn't be an issue here. I have given column B as call duration in minutes for simplicity here but it is in seconds in actual. Very rare to have call duration in seconds to be same.

Comment: Hey, what is going on here? Another person posted almost exactly the same question today. Are you guys taking an exam right now or something?

Comment: ohh..he asked me to help. I didn't know he already posted it here. It is a real world problem. Thanks.

Comment: @mathguy . I have edited the question to use the solution in a larger query. i wasn't aware initially that it needs to be used in a larger query. Can you please help one more time.

Comment: @Gurv. I have edited the question to use the solution in a larger query. i wasn't aware initially that it needs to be used in a larger query. Can you please help one more time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this if 12c+

```
select a
from t
group by a
order by count(*) desc, max(b) desc
fetch first 1 row only;
```

If 11g or lower:

```
select * from (
    select a
    from t
    group by a
    order by count(*) desc, max(b) desc
) where rownum = 1;
```

Note that if there is equal count and equal max value for two or more values of A, then any one of them will be fetched.

Comment: @Sammy . . . Updated.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Gurv. This is the best answer. All working now.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a query that will work in older versions (no `fetch` clause) and does not require a subquery. It uses the `first/last` function. In case of ties by both "count by A" and "value of max(B)" it selects only the row with the largest value of A. You can change that to `min(A)`, or even to `sum(A)` (although that probably doesn't make sense in your problem) or `LISTAGG(A, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY A)` to get a comma-delimited list of the A's that are tied for first place, but that requires 11.2 (I believe).

```
select   max(a) keep (dense_rank last order by count(b), max(b)) as a
       , max(max(b)) keep (dense_rank last order by count(b))    as b
from     inputs
group by a
;
```